# Why isn't my Genie keypad communicating with my Genie garage door opener?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

I've followed the steps outlined on the keypad.

press `3`,`5`,`7` `prog`

enter keycode between 3-8 digits, hit `prog`

press the `learn` button on the garage door opener

while the `learn` button light is blinking, enter the code and press the `open` button.

My issue is at this step.  The learn button light starts blinking, but when I enter the code, it doesn't turn from blinking to constantly on.  It seems the keypad is not communicating with the opener.  Any thoughts?

`EDIT`:

I know that the garage door will open and that it can receive wireless communication because I have a working wireless opener. It is also wired to an opener within the garage that can turn on the lights and open/close it.

Comment: Also, is there a good way to test if the keypad is actually broadcasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to call Genie customer service. They will be able to confirm if the keypad is truly compatible with your exact model opener. They can walk you through all possible troubleshooting steps while on the phone, and what the next step would be if they can't resolve your problem. The one time I called them the time on hold was minimal and I was not endlessly transferred around to find the right person.

Comment: Thanks.  Not a solution, I guess, but I think this is probably my best bet.